# Angular 5 - what's the benefit in having component variables as type Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable

I am new to *Angular 6* and have been reading about the `http` process in the below link:

**https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#create-herosearchcomponent**

I notice that in the component the type of the heroes array is `Observable`.

I'm not sure if this always needs to be the case inside components or not.

In my own code, I was able to data bind a non-observable:

```
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    data: object;

    constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.userInfoService
            .getEmployeeInfo()
            .subscribe((response) => {
              this.data = response;
            });
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the best practice is or what the pros and cons of each method are.

Comment: That is what makes `angular` a `reactive framework`.

Comment: I'm coming from AngularJS 1.5 and 1.5 uses promises. I'm still wrapping my head around the new http approach in v5.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your variable as Observable in this case - you have some chaining of `RxJS` operators and in your code you want to subscribe to the chaining flow many times. So for don't combining these operator every time, you can hold them in the property and add just one `.susbcribe` to it.

```
this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
  debounceTime(300),

  // ignore new term if same as previous term
  distinctUntilChanged(),

  // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
  switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
);

inOneMethod() {
   this.heroes$.subscribe(data => this.first = data);
}

inAnotherMethod() {
   this.heroes.subscribe(data => this.second = data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observable as a class variable is not compulsory.
Observable is based on the concept of using streams, wherein subscribers subscribe to whatever is emitted by this stream.

Whereas, in this case the HTTP response here by default is an observable to which you subscribe and further use whatever is emitted by this response stream.